# Android. Handler. Runnable

Tags: java, android

```
 public void DRAW() {
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    for (Object[] o : list) {
        final Object[] oo = o;
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if ((boolean) oo[0] == true) {
                    drawCM((boolean) oo[0], (int) oo[1], (boolean) oo[2]);
                } else {
                    draw((boolean) oo[0], (int) oo[1], (boolean) oo[2]);
                }

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }

    list.clear();
}
```

In an ArrayList i store data about 2 different categories of imageButtons. 
The draw() and drawCM() methods just change the background of the imageButtons.

As it is now, the code will change the background after 1 sec but for all the imageButtons I have data about in the list at the same time.

I want to change their background step by step, imageButton after imageButton.

Answer (score 0):

you adding a handler for each object, so you can simple change the delay for each, like 1000 next 2000 ...

alternative use only one handler, put your loop inside your run method, and add an delay et the end of the loop

Comment: if i put the loop inside the run method it does not change any backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int index;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler.post(changeBgRunnable);
    }

    List<Object[]> list = null;

    public Runnable changeBgRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (list != null && list.size() > index) {
                Object[] oo = list.get(index);
                if ((boolean) oo[0]) {
                    drawCM((boolean) oo[0], (int) oo[1], (boolean) oo[2]);
                } else {
                    draw((boolean) oo[0], (int) oo[1], (boolean) oo[2]);
                }

                index++;
                handler.postDelayed(changeBgRunnable, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    public void draw(boolean b, int i, boolean bb) {

    }

    public void drawCM(boolean b, int i, boolean bb) {

    }
}
```